# Why is it not possible to access a static field from a class instance?

Tags: static-members, haxe

In my understanding, a static member belongs to the class rather than to a specific instance of that class. It can be useful if either all instances share this specific characteristic with the exact same value, or if I do not want to create any instances of the class at all.

So, if I have a class `Car`, and all my cars will always have exactly 4 wheels, I could store the number of wheels as a static member of the class `Car` rather than as a instance variable of a `myCar` class instance.

But why should it be not possible in Haxe to access the static variable from a class instance? Doesn't make any sense to me.

```
class Car 
{ 
    public static var noOfWheels:Int = 4;

    public static function getNoOfWheels():Int
    {       
        return Car.noOfWheels;
    }   

}

class Main
{
    static function main() 
    {
        myCar = new Car();

        trace (myCar.noOfWheels);
        trace (myCar.getNoOfWheels());
        trace (Type.getClass(myCar).noOfWheels);
    }
}
```

Neither of those traces lead to the desired result. The first and second trace result in an error of the type:

> Cannot access static field XY from a class instance

while the third leads to:

> Class <Car> has no field noOfWheels

Edit for clarification:

I have several child classes of the `Car` class, inheriting all its properties. In some cases, like the class `ItalianVan`, I declare the static variable `noOfWheels` again, thus overshadowing the original `Car.noOfWheels`.

```
class ItalianVan extends Car 
{ 
    public static var noOfWheels:Int = 3;
}
```

Now, if I have an arbitrary car instance, I would like to know how many wheels it has. If I access the `Car.noOfWheels`, the answer would always be 4 wheels, even if that special car actually was a three-wheeled italian van.

Maybe the answer is: Don't use static variables for stuff like that!
But it isn't obvious to me why. 
Seems unnecessary to make `noOfWheels` an instance variable, if all members of that class have the same number of wheels.

Answer (score 3):

I've never used Haxe but I can see that you are accessing to the `myCar` variable.
Try this:

```
trace (Car.noOfWheels);
trace (Car.getNoOfWheels());
```

When you want to access to a static variable you should use the class name.

To access a static variable from an instance maybe you can add a non static method that returns the result of the static call.

Comment: This is correct: in Haxe, like most other languages, static variables must be accessed from the class name and not the instance name.

Comment: Thank you for your input. But what if I don't know the class name?

Comment: Usually there are methods like getClass or instanceOf that let you know the class of a variable, then you can access the static variable from that class.

Comment: Exactly! That's why I tried 
trace (Type.getClass(myCar).noOfWheels);

Comment: I see, good question. Maybe you can create a method in each class that extends the Car class that returns the noOfWheels using the static call.

Comment: I've posted a follow up question on why Type.getClass does not work:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746718/why-is-it-not-possible-to-access-static-fields-of-a-class-via-type-getclass

Comment: But the deeper question doesn't seem to have been answered: *why* in Java cannot ```instance.staticVar``` be permitted as an accessor to ```TheClass.staticVar```?  It seems unambiguous as to what it means, but what am I overlooking here?  (I note that in a method of TheClass, I can mention bare member names and they can be resolved to instance or class, regardless)