# Why is it not possible to access static fields of a class via Type.getClass()?

Tags: class, types, haxe

In Haxe, it is possible to get the class of an object with the following function:

```
Type.getClass(myObject);
```

If the object `myObject` is an instance of the class `myClass`, which contains a static field, I should be able to access this static field:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static myStaticField:Int = 5;
}

public var myObject = new MyClass();

//expected trace: "5"
trace (Type.getClass(myObject).myStaticfield);
```

But the result is:

> "Class <MyClass> has no field myStaticField."

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use reflection to get such value:

```
class Test {    
    @:keep public static var value = 5;

    static function main() {
        var test = new Test();
        var v = Reflect.field(Type.getClass(test), "value");
        trace(v);
    }

    public function new() {}
}
```

Note that to prevent DCE (dead code elimination) I had to mark the static var with `@:keep`. Normally DCE is going to suppress that variable because it is never referred directly.

Working example here: http://try.haxe.org/#C1612

Answer (score 1):

Try the Reflect class (Specifically the  [callMethod](http://api.haxe.org/Reflect.html#callMethod) or getProperty functions).